# Deserialized object type get value throw null reference

Tags: c#, object, nullreferenceexception

i have a json response from ajax and i am trying to deserialize it as object type(not a defined model class) and access its properties value. deserializer works fine but when try to get the value i get the null reference error.

```
// on break point i can clearly see the object properties and values and its not null
var tankJsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(tankJson);

//here from GetValue i get the null refernce error
var test = tankJsonObj.GetType().GetProperty("tankName").GetValue(tankJsonObj, null).ToString();
```

i tried the test data

```
var tankJsonObj = new { tankName = "xx" };
var test = tankJsonObj.GetType().GetProperty("tankName").GetValue(tankJsonObj, null).ToString();
```

and it works fine. i cant understand why the object that initiated by deserializer which is not null throwing the error on getting the property value.

[image: object value]

Comment: The cause is simple, `object` does not have a `tankName` property.

Comment: nio i have that ... question is edited now by image to be sure that tankName exists

Comment: okay now i see {{  tankName="" }} instead of { tankName = "" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>` returns [a `JObject` instance](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm). That class does not have a property called `tankName`, so `tankJsonObj.GetType().GetProperty("tankName")` returns `null`.

When you test using an anonymous type, that type *does* have a property called `tankName`.

You don't need reflection to extract values from a `JObject`:

```
JObject tankJsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(tankJson);
string tankName = tankJsonObj["tankName"]?.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `GetValue()` parameter needs to be **`tankJsonObj`** because from that object the values will be read.

Changed code:

```
var tankJsonObj = new { tankName = "xx" };
var test = tankJsonObj.GetType().GetProperty("tankName").GetValue(tankJsonObj, null).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(test); // "xx"
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tOtRUf

---

However when deserializing to `object`, only properties that `object` supports will be deserialized, and there are... none! As a result all properties inside the JSON will be ignored.

A simple workaround is to instead use `JObject` as the target type (in the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace). This behaves somewhat like a Dictionary of keys and values, and will accept any property. The resulting code is very simple, it doesn't even need reflection:

```
var tankJsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>("{ tankName: \"xx\" }");
var test = tankJsonObj.GetValue("tankName")?.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(test); // "xx"
```

Comment: both ways work ... of course for test one not deserialized one, i mentioned that the test one works but not for deserialized one. i checked again yours and still i have the same problem :(

Comment: i think the problem as break point shows is {{..... }} from deserialized data

Comment: See my update please.